# How to make an image's parts clickable on Android

Tags: android, xml

i have a PNG image (human body) i want to make each muscle of it clickable. And on select the muscle should change it s color any suggestion?

Comment: http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/

Comment: i checked this link before, i m looking for an easier way but thanks anyway i ll retake it into consideration. Thanks!

Comment: Above is the best option you have, but if you can cut your body image into different parts and make them work as different Imageviews, then you can easily put a click on them.